# How to return just the name using typehead and angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to return just the name equal in the text box type using typehead. I don't understand what are the parameters used in typehead can you help me, please. There is no showing on the textbox when you type a characters or letter. Here are the sample code and data.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="selectbiller" ng-model="vm.selectedBiller"
                   uib-typeahead="item as items.Name for items in vm.onNameEntry($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-editable="false"
                   typeahead-on-select="vm.onCarSelect($item, $model, $label)"
                   placeholder="Search a Car"
                   autocomplete="off"/>
```

AngularJs:

```
vm.onNameEntry = function(name) {
    return carService.searchCarByName({name: name})
        .$promise
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data && data.Items) {
                return data.Items;
            }

            return null;
        });
}
```

Data:

from, console.log(data);

```
Value:Array(8)
0:{Id: null, Name: "Innova"}
1:{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"}
2:{Id: null, Name: "BMW"}
3:{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"}
4:{Id: null, Name: "Honda"}
5:{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"}
6:{Id: null, Name: "Kia"}
7:{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 uib-typeahead="item as item.Name for item in vm.onNameEntry($viewValue) | filter:{Name:$viewValue}"
```

Here is a working jsfiddle example to match your requirement.
http://jsfiddle.net/harshakj89/gfbeLbke/1/

Comment: thanks friend it works! then I found my fault is returning a list of objects then I want to store them into a array I post another issues. please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*items* should be *item* as `vm.onNameEntry($viewValue)` returns a list of items

```
uib-typeahead="item as item.Name for item in vm.onNameEntry($viewValue)"
```

Comment: thanks friend it works! then I found my fault is returning a list of objects then I want to store them into a array I post another issues. please help thank you.